# Java Tomcat RequestDumperFilter logging problems

Tags: java, tomcat, web, servlets, servlet-filters

On my Tomcat server I have added the RequestDumperFilter to web.xml and my logging.properties file. Everything is working as it should except for something I noticed this morning.

The Web app I have will call to the backend every 5 seconds for various reasons. So if I click to a new page around the same time as this 5 second call the logs will get smashed together in the file output. I thought Java would wait until the file is done being used to write to it again.

Is there a way to guarantee that the logs will be sent to the file in order and not be smashed together?

Here is a link to RequestDumperFilter: [RequestDumperFilter Github](https://github.com/Oreste-Luci/apache-tomcat-8.0.26-src/blob/master/java/org/apache/catalina/filters/RequestDumperFilter.java)

My **web.xml** entry I added:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>requestdumper</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
```

My **logging.properties**:

```
...
handlers = ... 1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
...
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = request-dumper.
1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.VerbatimFormatter
org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.handlers = 1request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, that the Request Dumper may not necessarily log request and response one directly after the other in a multi page call / threading scenario, that's by design.
You got a processing thread id to differentiate the requests and they are separated by a `------------------` after the request and the same before the response is printed. Finially suffixed with some `================` line.